# Why didn't IP Man want to be a teacher?

Tags: ip-man

In the movie [IP Man (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1220719/), despite the fact that pretty much everyone wants IP to teach them how to fight, he seems really reluctant about it and only starts teaching during the war, when it is a matter of life and death.

Why was he so against taking disciples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Man is a peaceful person.  Wing Chun (the fighting style) was meant to defend the weak and to improve upon who you are as a person, not for violence and political agendas.  He did not want his style of fighting used to simply to further the agenda of others.  Once the war started affecting him personally and those around him, that's when IP Man decided it was time to teach Wing Chun.